# How to solve this maven project creation problem?

Tags: maven, project

when i try to create a maven project I follow the correct steps but project is not created and did not get any error on the screen but when I try to close the eclips it shows like "the user operation is waiting for creating "maven-archetype-quickstart" to complete "
what can I do please help me

[image]